# How does one write a method for an abstract class that returns the type of the implementation?

Tags: java, generics

I have a java abstract class called FooFactory. One of these methods is withDate which obviously indicates that I want to eventually build an implementation of Foo with a given Date.

My question is this. How do I return an instance of my implementation of FooFactory from withDate? Here is what I tried:

```
abstract class FooFactory<T extends FooFactory<T>>
{
    private date;

    public T withDate(Date date)
    {
        this.date = date;
        // Does not work
        return this;
    }

    public abstract Foo build();

    // more with methods and a build method
}
```

What I would like to then do is to have something like this:

```
public final class BarFooFactory extends FooFactory<BarFooFactory>
{
    @Override
    public BarFoo build()
    {
        BarFoo barFoo = new BarFoo()
        super.populateFooProperties(barFoo);
        return barFoo;
    }
}
```

For those curious why I just don't want to return a FooFactory, the reason is that the compiler will interpret future with calls and the build calls in the context of a FooFactory and thus I could not truly chain the calls.

Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: Shouldn't `BarFooFactory` extend `FooFactory`? Also, why are you using generics - I don't see their purpose here.

Comment: Yes. Fixed. The reason for using generics is so that I can reuse the logic in the FooFactory class in other factories that return implementations of Foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution I've seen applied to similar problems is to define a `getThis()` abstract method that returns the subclass instance. It avoids an unchecked cast warning, but may rankle some purists.

```
abstract class FooFactory<T extends FooFactory<T>> {
  private Date date;

  public abstract T getThis();

  public T withDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
    return getThis();
  }
```

Comment: Interesting solution. That would avoid the warning that @Makoto finds worrisome in my version of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. I simply needed to cast "this" to T when returning. So the code looks more like this:

```
abstract class FooFactory<T extends FooFactory<T>>
{
    private date;

    public T withDate(Date date)
    {
        this.date = date;
        // This works
        return (T) this;
    }

    public abstract Foo build();

    // more with methods and a build method
}
```

Now `new BarFooFactory().withDate(new Date())` returns a BarFooFactory instead of a FooFactory.

Comment: This is pretty worrisome; you're going to get an unchecked cast for that operation.

Comment: @Makoto But that would be perfectly type-safe. We can add `@SuppressWarnings` annotation. Or use `getThis()` approach as in other answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's worrisome. I can suppress the warning and I won't feel bad about it since I'm confident that the cast will always work.

If there is a way to write code that extends FooFactory where such a cast won't work, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: You might choose to create a concrete `getThis()` method in your abstract class, meaning that there's only one place where you suppress the warning.